# CheckBoxList – success, RadioButtonList – failure

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist, radiobuttonlist, modalpopupextender

A CheckBoxList and four RadioButtonLists are in the same .aspx file in different panels associated with different ModalPopupExtenders from the AjaxToolKit. I do not handle their SelectedIndexChanged Events. The state of the list elements is tested in button event handlers; the buttons also reside in those panels. The state of the CheckBoxList elements (in 'cblFlter') carries through to the handler of the OK button in the panel with the check box list. The state of the RadioButtonLists’ elements (in 'obl0' through 'obl3') does not carry through to the handler of the OK button in the panel with the radio button lists: when debugging the c# code, all four of them always have their first radio button selected, no matter which radio button I had clicked before clicking on OK, and regardless of having set their ‘Selected’ properties different for each radio button list in the markup.

Here is a partial listing of the .aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Title="List of Expenses" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/mTSoar.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Expenses.aspx.cs"
Inherits="TSoar.Accounting.FinDetails.ExpVendAP.Expenses" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderHeader" runat="server">
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="Accounting - Bookkeeping - Expenses, Vendors, Accounts Payable - Expenses" Font-Italic="true" />
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="MainContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<a href="XactExpense.aspx">Create New Expense Record</a>
.
.
.
<div id="ModPopExtFiltering">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Text="T" CssClass="displayNone" />
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModPopExtFilter" runat="server"
        TargetControlID="LinkButton2" PopupControlID="MPE_PanelFilter"
        BackgroundCssClass="background" />
    <asp:Panel ID="MPE_PanelFilter" runat="server" CssClass="popup" style="display:none;" HorizontalAlign="Center">
        Display those transactions with a status that is checked:
        <p>
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblFilter" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="UnorderedList" >
                <asp:ListItem>Active</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Voided</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Deleted</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Template</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </p>
        <p> <asp:Button ID="pbFilterOK" runat="server" Text="OK" OnClick="pbFilterOKCancel_Click" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="pbFilterCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="pbFilterOKCancel_Click" />
        </p>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>

<div id="ModPopExtSorting">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" Text="T" CssClass="displayNone" />
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModPopExtSort" runat="server"
        TargetControlID="LinkButton3" PopupControlID="MPE_PanelSort"
        BackgroundCssClass="background" />
    <asp:Panel ID="MPE_PanelSort" runat="server" CssClass="popup" style="display:none;" HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <table style="align-self:center">
            <tr>
                <td</td><td></td><td></td>
                <td>Sort Priority</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th></th><th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th><asp:Label runat="server" Text="1&nbsp;2&nbsp;3&nbsp;4" Font-Size="Medium" /></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date</td><td></td>
                <td><asp:RadioButtonList ID="obl0" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table"
                    EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                        <asp:ListItem> &nbsp; </asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem> &nbsp; </asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem> &nbsp; </asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"> &nbsp; </asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vendor</td><td></td>
                <td><asp:RadioButtonList ID="obl1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table"
                    EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                        <asp:ListItem> &nbsp; </asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem> &nbsp; </asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"> &nbsp; </asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem> &nbsp; </asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Status</td><td></td>
                <td><asp:RadioButtonList ID="obl2" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table"
                    EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                        <asp:ListItem> &nbsp; </asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"> &nbsp; </asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem> &nbsp; </asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem> &nbsp; </asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Amount</td><td></td>
                <td><asp:RadioButtonList ID="obl3" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table"
                    EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"> &nbsp; </asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem> &nbsp; </asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem> &nbsp; </asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem> &nbsp; </asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p> <asp:Button ID="pbSortOK" runat="server" Text="OK" OnClick="pbSortOKCancel_Click" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="pbSortCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="pbSortOKCancel_Click" />
        </p>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
.
.
.
```

Here is a partial listing of the .aspx.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using TSoar.DB;

namespace TSoar.Accounting.FinDetails.ExpVendAP
{
    public partial class Expenses : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
.
.
.

        protected void pbFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dtTFilter = AccountProfile.CurrentUser.XactFilterSettings;
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                cblFilter.Items[i].Selected = (bool)dtTFilter.Rows[i]["bFilter"];
            }
            ModPopExtFilter.Show();
        }

        protected void pbFilterOKCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button pb = (Button)sender;
            switch (pb.ID)
            {
                case "pbFilterOK":
                    DataTable dtTFilter = AccountProfile.CurrentUser.XactFilterSettings;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {
                        dtTFilter.Rows[i]["bFilter"] = cblFilter.Items[i].Selected;
                    }
                    AccountProfile.CurrentUser.XactFilterSettings = dtTFilter;
                    DisplayGrid();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        protected void pbSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RadioButtonList[] obla = new RadioButtonList[4];
            obla[0] = obl0;
            obla[1] = obl1;
            obla[2] = obl2;
            obla[3] = obl3;
            DataTable dtTSort = AccountProfile.CurrentUser.XactSortSettings;
            int rowIndex = 0;
            foreach(DataRow dr in dtTSort.Rows)
            {
                obla[rowIndex].ClearSelection();
                obla[rowIndex].Items[(int)dr["SortOrder"] - 1].Selected = true;
                rowIndex++;
            }
            ModPopExtSort.Show();
        }


        protected void pbSortOKCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button pb = (Button)sender;
            switch (pb.ID)
            {
                case "pbSortOK":
                    RadioButtonList[] obla = new RadioButtonList[4];
                    obla[0] = obl0;
                    obla[1] = obl1;
                    obla[2] = obl2;
                    obla[3] = obl3;
                    int iSum = 0;
                    foreach (XactSort.eSortBy es in Enum.GetValues(typeof(XactSort.eSortBy)))
                    {
                        for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++)
                        {
                            if (obla[(int)es].Items[j-1].Selected)
                            {
                                iSum += j * (int)(Math.Pow(10.0, j - 1) + 0.1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (iSum != 4321)
                    {
                        ProcessPopupException(new Global.excToPopup("Invalid Sort Priorities - each of Date, Vendor, Status, and Amount " +
                            "must be assigned a different sort priority between 1 and 4. [Checksum=" + iSum.ToString() + "]"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DataTable dtTSort = AccountProfile.CurrentUser.XactSortSettings;
                        foreach(XactSort.eSortBy es in Enum.GetValues(typeof(XactSort.eSortBy)))
                        {
                            for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++)
                            {
                                if (obla[(int)es].Items[j-1].Selected)
                                {
                                    dtTSort.Rows[(int)es]["SortOrder"] = j;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        AccountProfile.CurrentUser.XactSortSettings = dtTSort;
                        DisplayGrid();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
.
.
.
```

Do you need more info to help me solve this one?

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved by adding the 'Value' property to each RadioButtonList ListItem, as suggested by Martin Ullrich, like so (value property must be different for each ListItem within one RadioButtonList):

```
<div id="ModPopExtSorting">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" Text="T" CssClass="displayNone" />
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModPopExtSort" runat="server"
        TargetControlID="LinkButton3" PopupControlID="MPE_PanelSort"
        BackgroundCssClass="background" />
    <asp:Panel ID="MPE_PanelSort" runat="server" CssClass="popup" style="display:none;" HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <table class="center-block">
            <tr>
                <th></th><th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
                <th>Sort Priority</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date</td><td></td>
                <td><asp:RadioButtonList ID="obl0" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table" TextAlign="Left">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="1"/>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2"/>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3"/>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="4"/>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vendor</td><td></td>
                <td><asp:RadioButtonList ID="obl1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table" TextAlign="Left">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1"/>
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="2"/>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3"/>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="4"/>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Status</td><td></td>
                <td><asp:RadioButtonList ID="obl2" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table" TextAlign="Left">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1"/>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2"/>
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="3"/>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="4"/>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Amount</td><td></td>
                <td><asp:RadioButtonList ID="obl3" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table" TextAlign="Left">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1"/>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2"/>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3"/>
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="4"/>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p> <asp:Button ID="pbSortOK" runat="server" Text="OK" OnClick="pbSortOKCancel_Click" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="pbSortCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="pbSortOKCancel_Click" />
        </p>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

Comment: I was unable to find documentation on this in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist?view=netframework-4.7.2 ; under 'Declarative Syntax' the Value property is mentioned under ListItem, but no indication that it is required in order to determine the selected element upon PostBack (according to research by Martin Ullrich).